# RTK typescript errors with APIslice - CreateAPI

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

New to Typescript, I thought this would have been a common problem, couldn't really find anything helpful

Here's my API slice

```
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "apiSlice",
  prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
    headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
    headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    return headers;
  },
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
     baseUrl: "https://api.npoint.io",
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getWines: builder.query({
      query: () => `/0d9ec2e70191f0835e9a`,
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetDataQuery } = apiSlice;
```

**PrepareHeaders Error**
Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'prepareHeaders' does not exist in type 'CreateApiOptions<BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta>, { getWines: QueryDefinition<any, BaseQueryFn<...>, never, any, "apiSlice">; }, "apiSlice", never>'.ts(2353)

**UserGetDataQuery Error**
Property 'useDataQuery' does not exist on type 'Api<BaseQueryFn<string | FetchArgs, unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, {}, FetchBaseQueryMeta>, EndpointDefinitions, "apiSlice", never, unique symbol | unique symbol>'.ts(2339)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`prepareHeader`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/fetchBaseQuery#prepareheaders) is part of the `fetchBaseQuery` function API, not `createApi`. Move the `prepareHeaders` property into `fetchBaseQuery`.

Example:

```js
import { createApi, fetchBaseQuery } from "@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react";

export const apiSlice = createApi({
  reducerPath: "apiSlice",
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: "https://api.npoint.io",
    prepareHeaders: (headers) => {
      headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
      headers.set("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      return headers;
    },
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getWines: builder.query<ReturnValueTypeHere, void>({
      query: () => `/0d9ec2e70191f0835e9a`,
    }),
  }),
});
```

There isn't any `getData` endpoint declared so there will not be any `useGetDataQuery` hook generated. Given the code above only `useGetWines-X` hooks will be generated, e.g. `useGetWinesQuery`.

```js
export const { useGetWinesQuery } = apiSlice;
```

Comment: Thanks, in my code now 
const { data } = useGetWinesQuery(); 
Expected 1-2 arguments, but got 0.ts(2554), I don't need to provide any args? have I set it up wrong?

Comment: @Corey You should parameterize the query, basic usage is `builder.query<ReturnTypeHere, ArgumentTypeHere>`. Use `void` as the argument type if the query isn't passed an argument. See [Typing query and mutation endpoints](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage-with-typescript#typing-query-and-mutation-endpoints) for more information.